# How or Can I pass a function with argument as a parameter to a function in lua?

Tags: lua, computercraft

I am not running straight lua but the CC-Tweaks ComputerCraft version.  This is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.  It does not work as is.

*edited. I got a function to pass, but not one with arguments of its own.

```
function helloworld(arg)

    print(arg)

end

function frepeat(command)

    for i=1,10 do

        command()

    end

end

frepeat(helloworld("hello"))
```

Comment: lhf and aschelper have posted different, but equally good, answers. Maybe they should be combined into one answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function helloworld(arg)
    print(arg)
end

function frepeat(command,arg)
    for i=1,10 do
        command(arg)
    end
end

frepeat(helloworld,"hello")
```

If you need multiple arguments, use `...` instead of `arg`.

Answer (score 3):

```
frepeat(helloworld("hello"))
```

will not pass the `helloworld` function like `frepeat(helloworld)` does, because it always means what it looks like: call `helloworld` once, then pass that result to `frepeat`.

You need to define a function doing what you want to pass that function. But an easy way to do that for a single-use function is a function expression:

```
frepeat( function () helloworld("hello") end )
```

Here the expression `function () helloworld("hello") end` results in a function with no name, whose body says to pass `"hello"` to `helloworld` each time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

"repeat" is reserved word in lua. Try this:

```
function helloworld()
    print("hello world")
end
function frepeat(command)
    for i=1,10 do
        command()
    end
end
frepeat(helloworld)
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, unfortunately I asked the wrong question and had to edit my question.  I did however change the function name in my example.

Comment: @marcm Change question after answer not goog idea. But in you case solution is simple. Just replace "frepeat(helloworld)" to "frepeat(function() helloworld("hello") end)" as described in next answer from aschepler.